# Not sure how to see my search results for Django-haystack?

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I recently set up django and haystack and I have no errors but How do I see my search results? It made no mention of setting up a view for it only a template and a url. The action in the form template is this

```
<form method="get" action=".">
```

that didn't work so I changed it to this

```
<form method="get" action="posts/search">
```

and I also tried this with the slash after search

```
<form method="get" action="posts/search/">
```

I also tried to give my url a name

```
url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls'), name='search'),
```

and have the form like this

```
<form method="GET" action="{% url 'posts:search' %}">
```

when I tried it like that it gave me this error

```
django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'search' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

how do I link my app properly to server so that the results display properly

heres my code
my form in my nav. the action is a page I had created before haystack the ones above are the new ones

```
<form method="GET" action="{% url 'posts:search-page' %}"  class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
    <div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" id="search" placeholder="search" value="{{ request.GET.q }}">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">search</button>
            </span>
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
     </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</form>
```

my posts/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from .views import post_create, post_detail, post_list, post_update, post_delete, post_search, tag_list

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', post_list, name='list'),
    url(r'^create/$', post_create, name='create'),
    url(r'^search_results/$', post_search, name='search-page'),
    url(r'^tag/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', tag_list, name="tag_list"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', post_detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/$', post_update, name='update'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/delete/$', post_delete, name='delete'),
    url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
]
```

my searche_indexes.py

```
from haystack import indexes
from .models import Post


class NoteIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    publish = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='publish')

    # content_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='title')

    def get_model(self):
        return Post

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

my templates/search/search.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Search</h2>

<form method="get" action=".">
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Search">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    {% if query %}
        <h3>Results</h3>

        {% for result in page.object_list %}
            <p>
                <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object.title }}</a>
            </p>
        {% empty %}
            <p>No results found.</p>
        {% endfor %}

        {% if page.has_previous or page.has_next %}
            <div>
                {% if page.has_previous %}<a href="?q={{ query }}&amp;page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">{% endif %}&laquo; Previous{% if page.has_previous %}</a>{% endif %}
                |
                {% if page.has_next %}<a href="?q={{ query }}&amp;page={{ page.next_page_number }}">{% endif %}Next &raquo;{% if page.has_next %}</a>{% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        {# Show some example queries to run, maybe query syntax, something else? #}
    {% endif %}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

my post_text.txt

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.body }}
```

my Post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location,
                              null=True,
                              blank=True,
                              width_field="width_field",
                              height_field="height_field")
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    content = models.TextField()
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    publish = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    objects = PostManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-timestamp", "-updated"]
```

as I said I got no system errors. This Is my 4th time attempting to use this. And Now there are no errors, Just some issue that has to do with displaying my results. Any guidance in the right direction is welcome

Comment: What is not working? No data being showed on the results page or your result page is not loading at all? Did you create a search index? What engine are you using to create the index? SOLR? Whoosh? Did you read this? http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html

Comment: I used solr. And I follwed everything on that page to a T. Yes I created a search index. its above. If you mean search_index.py

Comment: So what happens when you submit the search form? What is your results page or your terminal showing? "Not working" is too broad. You need to be more specific and debug in step-by-step order.  Are your URLs/views working? Can you pass another context into the results page?

Comment: am I suppose to create a view for it in views.py even tho the docs don't say that?

Comment: Look inside the Haystack folder under lib/python2.7/site-packages. It will tell you more about how it works. You can also create custom views by importing `from haystack.query import EmptySearchQuerySet` into your views or even customizing the search forms. You can copy the `basic_search` class from the Haystack and use it in your views. I have it hacked quite a bit as I do also have Ajax search suggestions in place of the search box.